# the tag of "LANGUAGE" in the Cambridge Dictionary

Tags: terminology

There are two different meanings of "complement" [on the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/complement).

> to make something else seem better or more attractive when combining with it

and

> a part of a clause that usually follows the verb in English and adds more information about the subject or object

with the latter, the dictionary tags it as "LANGUAGE"

[image]

I guess the tag means the word "complement" serves as a **English grammar term** with that meaning.

By "term", I mean

> a word or expression used in relation to a particular subject, often to describe something official or technical

> [From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/term)

In this context, the "particular subject" is English grammar.

In contrast, the first meaning does not serves as a term. Could I call it "**plain English**"?

Similarly, ["antonym"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/antonym) is an English grammar term while ["opposite"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/opposite) is not.

Is my understanding correct?

If that is what it means, why the dictionary doesn't give ["synonym"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/synonym) that tag? If "synonym" is just plain English, what is the corresponding English grammar term?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. If the presentation of this dictionary isn't clear to you, consider just using a different dictionary.

Comment: 2nd definition: It means that the word "complement" is often used in the field of  language learning or language teaching, note the word *specialized* which accompanies it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you. "often used in some field", does it fit the definition of "term"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. "In the field of something" means the topic/subject or work that one is involved with.